# Is it possible to get the result of PHP crypt(rounds=Y) by doing crypt(rounds=Y/2) twice

Tags: php, cryptography, md5, password-protection, password-encryption

What I want to do it to have something like this

```
$res_5a = crypt($password, '$6$rounds=5000$'.$salt.'$');
$res_25 = crypt($password, '$6$rounds=2500$'.$salt.'$');
$res_5b = crypt($res_25, '$6$rounds=2500$'.$salt.'$');
echo ($res_5a==$res_5b); //should be true
```

I tried playing with the $res_25 string but still can't get the result I want. I assume that crypt() does something non-trivial with it and wonder if there is an easy way to do this.

I intend to use this in the following way. When user registers, the password is encrypted using 5k rounds and the result is stored in DB (5k is just an example, let's assume that it's secure enough). Salt helps us make sure that rainbow tables can't be used while rounds protect us against brute force. If the DB is stolen, passwords can't be decrypted back and the attacker won't be able to use these passwords elsewhere where users could have used the same password.

Our site itself has a "remember me" feature on the sign in form. When it is not used, everything is ok - we store user's state in server session which dies eventually. However when user wants to use "remember me", we need to use cookie to store data that can be used to authenticate the user. Whatever we store in the cookie - whether it is the original password or something like md5($res_5a), if attacker steals the $res_5a value and steals the algorithm behind cookie creation, they'll be able to use this data to forge the cookie that would authenticate the user.

What I wanted to do is to have sign in form create $res_25 cookie. And then whenever a page is loaded, server will be adding 2.5k more iterations and checking whether the value matches the $res_5a stored in the DB. That way if $res_5a gets stolen, attacker won't be able to calculate the $res_25 value required to authenticate the user.

Comment: According to the PHP spec, crypt($string [,$salt]); I don't know what you are doing with "rounds," but everything in that single quote will be added with the salt (to my knowledge). (EDIT: Ignore this, I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Introduction**

It can never be the same ... because you are no longer hashing the original `string` after the second `crypt` call ... What do i mean

```
$salt = "salt";
$password = "password";
$res_5a = crypt($password, '$6$rounds=5000$'.$salt.'$');
$res_25 = crypt($password, '$6$rounds=2500$' . $salt . '$');
$res_5b = crypt($res_25, '$6$rounds=2500$'.$salt.'$');


var_dump($password,$res_5a,$res_25,$res_5b);
```

Output

```
string 'password' (length=8) <----------- Original Text

string '$6$rounds=5000$salt$IxDD3jeSOb5eB1CX5LBsqZFVkJdido3OUILO5Ifz5iwMuTS4XMS130MTSuDDl3aCI6WouIL9AjRbLCelDCy.g.' (length=106)
       |------------------|
         Custom Header for 500 rounds 

string '$6$rounds=2500$salt$e9Ui0CoNFtgwugogNU.uUwCKW8hAeW4td1ySwKf34FqEwMf2Gpk3zu5Y43R5a2AaI/5lpPigk1rSTme.uotYL1' (length=106)
       |------------------|
          Custom header would be added .. you are no onder encoding password

string '$6$rounds=2500$salt$JAq/IG3jH6w7r6S/AT/UhMpgLopLOWLbilJWY9z39s6To109QJvLxZJUkV99arSOSumFbS3Fy00CRAYrAd9Pp1' (length=106)
       |------------------|
         Even Final output would not be same as $6$rounds=5000$salt
```

**Solution**

A better way would be use security **Token Hash** and never store the username & or password on the system

The Token may have `User Agent` , `OS` , `Screen Resolution` in the hash combination just to make sure you are in the same environment

Also try to use [Http_only](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) cookies Example be of of [Security Implications](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html)

```
  session_set_cookie_params(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE);
                                                   ^----- Http Only
```

Comment: Yeah, however even after playing with the $res_25, removing custom header and applying the next 2.5k iteration to the headerless result, it still didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, Token might be what I end up doing. I was hoping for a simpler solution though (just do X more iterations) :)

Comment: The cycle is like a file pointer .. when you get to 2500 ... you can not continue form there it would start from 0 when you call it again. The incremental  values also has effect on encryption